# undefined method `it' for main:Object (NoMethodError) Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

Writing a rspec test to check the association is valid. My code follows

**Model**

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  require 'carrierwave/orm/activerecord'
  mount_uploader :file, FileUploader
  belongs_to :contact
  belongs_to :company

end
```

**Comment_spec**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Comment do
  pending "add some examples to (or delete) #{__FILE__}"
end

   it "should relate to comapny" do 
     Comment.reflect_on_association(:company).should_not be_nil
   end
```

I don't have any validation, and don't really need to test anything apart from the association. I get the following error:

```
 `<top (required)>': undefined method `it' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

I have an undefined method 'it' I don't seem to understand how I can declare this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `it` block isn't in a `describe` block. Try the following:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Comment do
  pending "add some examples to (or delete) #{__FILE__}"


   it "should relate to comapny" do 
     Comment.reflect_on_association(:company).should_not be_nil
   end 

end
```